# Looping a command in a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
cd \Users\Kurashima\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
adb devices
adb shell screenrecord /storage/ext_sd/vid001.mp4
adb shell screenrecord /storage/ext_sd/vid002.mp4
adb shell screenrecord /storage/ext_sd/vid003.mp4
```

Before getting to my question, I must first make a disclaimer.  I am a beginner in writing batch files.

What I want to do is to make those last three lines into a loop that will execute any number of times, incrementing the number in the file name, until the Ctrl+C command is entered.  I know how to make a simple loop, using :start and goto start, but I'd end up overwriting the same file every time.  How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete script. Remove all `REM` to make it operational for you.

Note `pause >NUL` command waits for pressing any key (without prompting due to `>NUL`); after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it will ask for `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`.

Remove that `pause >NUL` line if you want to work unattended; the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> functionality should retain; if does not retain, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
rem cd \Users\Kurashima\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
rem adb devices
set /A "ii=0"
:start
set /A "ii+=1"
set "ss=000%ii%"
set "ss=%ss:~-3%"
echo adb shell screenrecord /storage/ext_sd/vid%ss%.mp4
rem adb shell screenrecord /storage/ext_sd/vid%ss%.mp4
pause >NUL
if %ii% LSS 999 goto :start
:endlocal
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```